# grunt task using node http gets "no app" response from node app in heroku

Tags: node.js, http, heroku

I run grunt tasks that ping my node app. To develop. The locally running node app responds accordingly. When I deploy to heroku, however, and point tasks there, I get "No Heroku App" html pages from heroku.

Curl DOES work: curl 'myApp.herokuapp.com&some=stuff'. So I know that the deployed node app is working. What is wrong with the way I am parameterizing the http call from grunt?

```
grunt.registerTask("testGet", function(){
        var done = this.async();
        var options = {
        host: 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com',
        //host: "127.0.0.1",
        //port: 8000,
        path: "/myResource?"+qs.stringify({user_id:0, device:0}),
        method: "GET"
    };
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) { 
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            grunt.log.write(chunk + "\n");
        })
        done() 
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('problem with get: ' + err.message);
    });
    req.end();
  })
```

I've tried various things: moving the query params into the body, hard coding them, hard coding the heroku port, adding various headers. But the pings don't even show up in the heroku logs.

Weird thing is, it worked, once, right after a deploy, one time, then not after that, and not again after a deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`host: 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com',` should be: `host: 'myapp.herokuapp.com',`